# Playing 720 hd mp4 video from url on Android VideoView just working from Android 6, giving error in older versions

Tags: android, video-streaming, mp4, android-videoview

I'm trying to play a video from url in Android VideoView. It works on Android 6 but not working at all in previous versions. It throws a

> "Can't play video" error (E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -38) in log)

It's a 1280 x 720 .mp4 with codec H.264 and AAC audio video. Here is code, nothing special, with permissions for Internet and others granted in the manifest. I'm testing with different ADV emulators. Maybe is something with the resolution of the video, because with other video smaller it works like a charm.

```
public class VideoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    VideoView videoView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

        videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);

        //Creating MediaController
        MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

        //specify the location of media file
        Uri uri=Uri.parse("https://.........hd720.mp4");

        //Setting MediaController and URI, then starting the videoView
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        videoView.requestFocus()


        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                videoView.start();
            }
        });
}
```

Any suggestion? thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to confirm - have you tried to play it on physical device(s)?

Comment: @MorrisonChang i tested in android 6 and working in emu and physical but only testrd in emulator on older versions because i don't have physical devices with old versions. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Using the emulator to test video playback has been problematic in the past. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582016/how-to-play-mp4-video-in-android-emulator-using-remote-url  While it may have improved with HAXM, your best test is still the physical devices.

Comment: @MorrisonChang ok thanks